# In PHP, how do I query a mySQL database using multiple "IN" statements across different tables?

Tags: mysql, nested

I am trying to figure out how to have two "IN" statements.

I'm trying to get something like this, although I don't know how to use both of the nested select statements.

```
$query_row=mysql_query(
    "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table_a WHERE field_1 IN 
        (SELECT field_1 FROM table_b WHERE field_2 = $field_2), 
        (SELECT field_3 FROM table_c WHERE field_4 = $field_4)
        ORDER BY field_5 DESC
        ");
```

If I remove one of the `(SELECT...` bits, it works, but trying to put them both does not.

Table a has matching values in tables B and C: fields 2 and 4 respectively.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending if you want to test if IN either or both:

```
WHERE field_1 IN (SELECT field_1 FROM table_b WHERE field_2 = $field_2) AND/OR field_1 IN (SELECT field_3 FROM table_c WHERE field_4 = $field_4) ...
```

Comment: That's it.  I didn't realize I needed to put "AND field_1 IN", I was just trying "AND IN".  So yeah that makes perfect sense, and this was awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try it with a UNION:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM table_a 
    WHERE field_1 IN (SELECT field_1 FROM table_b WHERE field_2 = $field_2 
                      UNION 
                      SELECT field_3 FROM table_c WHERE field_4 = $field_4)
    ORDER BY field_5 DESC
```

Comment: Although that does work, the other guy's answer was specifially what I was looking for.

Still, ++ for you!

Comment: Alas, foiled by my old nemesis, "the other guy" once again.